# After using navigationLink to some views, how to go back to the first view in tab view?

Tags: swiftui

There are some view with in my tabview, For example, if I use navigationLink to TeamDetail3, can I use a button and return to the TeamListView(first view)? I don't know if @Environment(.presentationMode) or other approach can do the effect like this. Any comments would be appreciated.

```
struct MainView: View {
@State var selectedtab:Int = 1
@Binding var isNavigationBarHidden : Bool

var body: some View {
    TabView (selection: $selectedtab){
        UserInformationView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                Text("1")
            }.tag(0)
            .navigationBarTitle("1")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)


        TeamListView()
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.3.fill")
                Text("2")
            }.tag(1)
            .navigationBarTitle("2")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
        .navigationBarTitle("main")
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    })

}
}
```

My TeamListView and their subview like this:

```
struct TeamListView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userToken : UserToken


var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
       NavigationLink(destination: TeamDetail1()) {         
          Text("go to next page")
       }

    }
}
}


struct TeamDetail1: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userToken : UserToken


var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: TeamDetail2()) {         
          Text("go to next page")
       }

    }
}
}

struct TeamDetail2: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userToken : UserToken


var body: some View {
       NavigationLink(destination: TeamDetail3()) {         
          Text("go to next page")
       }
    }
}
}

struct TeamDetail3: View {

@EnvironmentObject var userToken : UserToken


var body: some View {
       Button(action:{}) {         
          Text("return to first page")
       }

    }
}
}
```